# Socket.io in route with Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I try to add a socket in a route, like that. But it feel like it never enter in the app.get() when I emit there. Is it something about expressJS routing or I can't do something like that ? And is it possible to use a variable to stream ?

```
app.get('/users/:iduser', function(req, res) { 
  console.log(req.params)
  io.on( "connection", function ( socket ) {
    console.log( 'Server: Incoming connection.' );
    socket.on( req.params.iduser, function ( msg, callback ) {
      console.log('Posts ')
      console.log(msg);
    } );
  })
});
```

I try to emit like that :

```js
const socket = io(`http://localhost:3012/users/iamtheiduser`);

socket.emit(iamtheiduser, {
  idUser: iamtheiduser
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608574/how-to-use-socket-io-instance-on-multiple-files-in-express-js-app/61692261#61692261

Answer (score 0):

Ya it is Possible to inside app.get() inside emit a socket.
But First, you need to Listen to a server properly and Established a DB Connection DBName(Like **MongoDB, MYQSQL**, etc). you used.

then use `io = require('socket.io').listen(server.listener);`
 Instead of `io(`http://localhost:3012/users/iamtheiduser`);`

And After that create a Socket connection and check that socket is Connected successfully or Not.

```
 io.on( "connection", function ( socket ) {
    console.log( 'Server: Incoming connection.' );
    socket.on( req.params.iduser, function ( msg, callback ) {
      console.log('Posts ')
      console.log(msg);
    } );
  })
```

you can use*[socket.IO Tester Google-chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm?hl=en)* for a testing purpose check socket connection created or not. and after that socket connection SuccessFully  Established, then you can easily Emit the data. please refer[socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/) it is helpful for you in sockets connection and emitting or Listening to a data In Both Client & serverSide. thanks :)